# DiscordAPI How to get sent images?(Python)

Tags: python, image, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to teach my Discord Bot to recognize text from images that are sent to it. This is how I wanted to do it:
"!totext " 
But I don't know how to catch sent images. Please help!

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def totext(ctx, arg):  
     await ctx.send(pytesseract.image_to_string(arg,lang="rus"))
```

Comment: But what are you passing as `arg`?  Is the image attached to the message, a url, in an embed, some string representation? What format is it in?

Comment: You can't get an image as an argument but you could get the attachments of the message with `ctx.message.attachments` You could use `ctx.message.attachments[0].url`